# Docker exasol image now working on arm64 mac machine

Tags: docker, macos, arm64, exasol

on running exasol docker image(below command) on arm64 machine, container is starting with errors

`docker run --name exasoldb1111  -p 127.0.0.1:9563:8563 --detach --privileged --stop-timeout 120 -v exa_volume:/exa exasol/docker-db`

unable to connect to db and seeing below logs.Is there a way to make exasol work

```
2023-08-13 23:39:02 [2023-08-13 18:09:02.466344 +00:00] stage4: Run service storage_volumes
2023-08-13 23:39:02 [2023-08-13 18:09:02.490974 +00:00] stage4: Run service virtserverd
2023-08-13 23:39:02 [2023-08-13 18:09:02.491764 +00:00] stage4: Run service webuibackend
2023-08-13 23:39:02 [2023-08-13 18:09:02.499186 +00:00] Started child /opt/exasol/cos-8.35.0/share/webui_backend/db-restapi (PID: 645) returns with errno set to "No such file or directory".
2023-08-13 23:39:02 [2023-08-13 18:09:02.499754 +00:00] child 645 (membership) returned with state 2.
2023-08-13 23:39:02 [2023-08-13 18:09:02.501295 +00:00] stage4: Run service databases
2023-08-13 23:39:02 No nodes to synchronize.
2023-08-13 23:39:03 No nodes to synchronize.
2023-08-13 23:39:03 [2023-08-13 18:09:03.189787 +00:00] Started /opt/exasol/cos-8.35.0/bin/dwa_wrapper with PID:673 UID:500 GID:500 Part:22 Node:0
2023-08-13 23:39:03 [2023-08-13 18:09:03.419912 +00:00] Started /opt/exasol/db-8.21.0/bin/pddserver with PID:707 UID:500 GID:500 Part:23 Node:0
2023-08-13 23:39:04 [2023-08-13 18:09:04.678552 +00:00] child 707 (Part:23 Node:0 pddserver) returned with state 1.
2023-08-13 23:39:06 [2023-08-13 18:09:06.458999 +00:00] child 673 (Part:22 Node:0 controller) returned with state 1.
```

I am using docker desktop version 4.22.0, also tried after enabling "Use Rosetta for x86/amd64 emulation on Apple Silicon" but no luck.

Thanks in advance for any help